# document.getElementById retuning is not updating dynamically in vue.js returning null every time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

js
I have a method to enable and disable print option which has element id printReport_AId, so the existence of element is dynamic based on selection.
I have a code to get

```
document.getElementById('printReport_AId')
```

this returning null everytime , i guess we need something like windows onload or interval method , not sure how to implement in vue.js

I have attached the code below

```
<template>

      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
       <div class="printIconSection"   v-for="report in reports" :key="report.property" >
          <div class="Icon" id="printReport_AId" v-if="isOverview">
             <font-awesome-icon :icon="report.icon" @click="printWindow()"/>
        </div>
      </div>

     <div class="logo"v-bind:class="{ 'non-print-css' : noprint }"> 
     </div>
      </div>
</template>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {
               timestamp: ''
            },
            created() {

            },
            methods: {
              printWindow() { },

mounted() {
    // window.addEventListener('print', this.noprint);
    },

computed(){
    noprint() {
        const printicon = document.getElementById('printReport_AId');
        if (printicon != 'null') {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
  },
   }

            }
         });
      </script>
<style>
@media print {
    .non-print-css {
        display: none;
    }
}

</style>
```

i just tried  window.addEventListener that didnt worked for computed .

I need to get the element id dynamically.

whenever i enable the print element , the element id should not be null. similarly,
whenever i dont enable the  print element , the element id should  be null

Comment: first of all dont put computed property to event listener. Second thing is that all document.get... should be in mounted lifecycle method inside of nextick function

Comment: you can read about next tick in documentation for vue

Comment: That is not how you get references to elements, read the documentation  
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: Warning: your `printReport_AId` ID is not unique, since you're wrapping it inside an outer element that contains the `v-for` directive.

Answer (score 0):

`computed` would not watch for document methods, because it is not wrapped with vue's setters and getters.

What you can do is mark your `div` with `ref` and then access it via `this.$refs`

```
<div class="printIconSection"   v-for="(report, index) in reports" :key="report.property" >
          <div class="Icon" :ref="'printReport_AId' + index" v-if="isOverview">
             <font-awesome-icon :icon="report.icon" @click="printWindow()"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
methods(){
    noprint(index) {
        const printicon = this.$refs['printReport_AId' + index];
        if (printicon != null) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
}
```

When you need to achieve noprint you just call `noprint(index)`
For each element of array `noprint` would be different

Comment: Note that this might not be sufficient, since the element is wrapped inside a `v-for` directive: this means that there will be multiple references. Some kind of index signature is required to access the correct reference.

Comment: I edited my answer, guess it would help.

Pay attention that I moved `noprint` from computed to methods, so you have to call it with parentheses and provide index into that.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you're inserting the ID in each iteration of the `v-for` loop. This means that the ID will not be unique in the event that there is more than one entry in your `reports` array. Based on your code, this is what I understand that you want to achieve:

- each report will contain an `isOverview` property. It is probably a boolean, so it has a value of `true` or `false`
- when `isOverview` is true, the print icon will be shown
- when `isOverview` is false, the print icon will not be shown
- based on whether the print icon(s) are shown, you want to toggle the `.logo` class

This comes the tricky part, as you have multiple `isOverview` to evaluate. Do you want to toggle the `.logo` element when:

- **all** reports has `isOverview` property set to true, or
- **one or more** reports has `isOverview` property set to true?

---

If you want to show the `.logo` element when all reports has `isOverview` set to true, then you can do this:

```
computed() {
    noprint() {
        return this.reports.every(report => report.isOverview);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you only want one or more report to have `isOverview` as true, you can do this instead:

```
computed() {
    noprint() {
        return this.reports.some(report => report.isOverview);
    }
}
```